# como modificar un archivo json

Tags: php, mysql, json, php5

mi base de datos tiene los siguientes campos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero necesito si o si traerlo en forma de `JSON` ya lo logre pero no como deberia lo traigo con el siguiente codigo:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$pdo=new PDO("mysql:dbname=automatizacion;host=localhost","root","root");
$sentenciaSQL = $pdo->prepare("SELECT `id_reunion`, `fecha`, `nombre_reunion`,`hora_inicio`, `hora_final` FROM `tbl_reunion` WHERE `id_reunion` = 1");
$sentenciaSQL->execute();

$resul= $sentenciaSQL->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($resul);
var_dump($resul);
?>
```

y perfecto me lo trae tal cual los campos de la base de datos de la siguiente manera:

```
 [
      {"id_reunion":"1",
       "fecha":"2021-06-18",
       "nombre_reunion":"Horas VOAE",
       "hora_inicio":"10:55:00",
       "hora_final":"12:55:00"
       }
    ]
```

hasta aquí todo perfecto pero quisiera modificarlo un poco por ejemplo cambiar en el JSON los nombre de las columnas y unir la fecha con la hora, lo quiero traer exactamente de la siguiente manera:

id_reunion por "id"
hora_inicio por "start" y unir con la fecha
hora_final por "end" y unir con fecha
nombre_reunion por "title"

```
[
 {"id":"1",
  "start":"2021-06-18 10:55:00",
  "title":"Horas VOAE",
  "end":"2021-06-18 12:55:00"
 }
]
```

he estado intentando y nada, se que se soluciona cambiando los campos por esos nombres pero esta tabla no se puede modificar porfavor alguien si me puede ayudar!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma de hacerlo, y sin modificar el código, es directo de la consulta SQL

```
$sentenciaSQL = $pdo->prepare(
    "SELECT `id_reunion` AS id, CONCAT(`fecha`, " ", `hora_inicio`) AS start, 
    `nombre_reunion` AS title, CONCAT(`fecha`, " ", `hora_final`) AS end 
    FROM `tbl_reunion` 
    WHERE `id_reunion` = 1"
);
```

En vez de tener fecha y horas en columnas separadas, podrías diseñarlas como DATETIME y guardar la fecha en formato completo `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`. Si solo necesitaras la fecha, o la hora, se puede especificar en la consulta.
Además, ¿qué pasa si el evento es tarde en la noche y la hora final se pasa del cambio de fecha?

Comment: Estaba siguiendo esta pregunta, gracias por tu respuesta que da una solución muy eficaz.